# How to throw an exception if there is related data on deleting

Tags: entity-framework

I have this object:

```
public class Profile
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public List<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

and I have a page to delete profiles.. so I want to delete a profile if there is not users related..

I tried this:

```
var profile = _db.Profile
.Include(p => p.Users)
.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

_db.Profile.Remove(profile);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

but this automatically delete all users related(I don't undestand why since I don't set any especial configuration for that).

How can I avoid this? 
How can I get a exception when I try to SaveChanges?

I would love to avoid checking the `Users.Count` directly in my code to do it.

Comment: Database first ? Code First ?

Comment: and, sorry, which version of ef ?

Comment: It's is the version 5.0.

Comment: well, take a look at this : http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/12/17/ef4-cpt5-code-first-remove-cascading-deletes.aspx It's for 4.1 CTP5, but I think it should be valuable.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Great :)
Can you answer this? so I can check as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the extension method

```
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

for a specific relation,

or disable all delete cascade with the `OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
   }
```

[This](http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/12/17/ef4-cpt5-code-first-remove-cascading-deletes.aspx) will show you some more details (EF 4 CTP5, but should be valuable)